# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fetch local api made in asp.net api which is running in `https://localhost:44388/`. When I tried to fetch get request it responds ok but return html not json. The problem might occur by two reasons:
1.typo in url (But I checked in my browser, it worked)
2.Server restart needed
What might be the problem with my code?

```
componentDidMount(){

    var proxyUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/";
    var targetUrl = "https://127.0.0.1:44388/api/product/getproducts";

    fetch(proxyUrl+targetUrl, {
      method:'GET',
      headers:{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Mehods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'*',
        'Content-type':'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(data=>{
        if(!data.ok){
          throw new Error("Error");
        }else{
          return data.json();
        }
      })
      .then(data=>this.setState({products:data}))
    }
```

Comment: Can you share getproducts data ?

Comment: My browser gives: and I checked on https://jsonlint.com/ to test validity:{
 "data": [{
   "productId":1,"productName": "tshirt"
  },
  {
   "productId":2,"productName": "Shoes"
  },
  {
   "productId":3,"productName": "Jacket"
  },
  {
   "productId":4,"productName": "UnderGarment"
  },
  {
   "productId":5,"productName": "Pants"
  }
 ],
 "isSuccess": true,
 "errorMessage": null
}

Comment: Input console.log(typeof data) above 'if(!data.ok){' and check type of data.
if it is already object, you don't need to use data.json(). Just input this.setState({products:data})

Comment: Yeah Its Object type. If I setState to that I get this:{products: Response}
products: Response
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/https://127.0.0.1:44388/api/product/getproducts"
__proto__: Response
__proto__: Object >>>not real data. Its just response object only not json.

Comment: I got it. I will edit answer

Comment: I think resonse data is not json. Can you change to data.text() and check value?

Comment: If I do so It prints html file of index.html

Comment: Ahh.. please change your code proxyUrl+targetUrl to targetUrl

Comment: After I do that It throws two errors:1.Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44388/api/product/getproducts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. and 2.Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Yes. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
If you open cors to localhost:3000, It will works with your code.
It is back-end problem

Comment: @leo-boy Consider installing Chrome CORS extension while developing locally or setting up CORS headers to allow anyone.

Comment: thank you @bkm412 for your help. I had problem with enabling cors in my backend.

Answer (score 0):

when you give parameter as:`proxyUrl+targetUrl`,
actually the url which you have called is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/https://127.0.0.1:44388/api/product/getproducts
```

which does not seems to be correct.

i think the structure of url you'v given to fetch function is wrong.